# How can I share my printer on different NAT?

Tags: nat, subnet

Hello I am facing a problem. Here I am attaching an image file where my problem diagram is drawn. Please look at the image before read this problem. There you will get a clear view about the problem.[image]

Here you can see the mother router is a Mikrotik 450G router and which doesn't have any wifi function. This router is connected with a Netgear switch. This router broadcast address of (192.168.1.*) series. There are 3 PCs connected via Ethernet LAN (192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.147 and 192.168.1.125) and a printer (Canon LBP3300) is attached with the PC 192.168.1.147 and shared over the network. The other two PC (192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.125) along with the attached PC found the printer easily and can do printing jobs. But as Mikrotik 450G doesn't support WIFI so another wifi enabled router is connected with the router via Ethernet cable and which received IP from the Mikrotik router is 192.168.1.130 and broadcast addresses 10.0.0.* series on it's own network. This is a Netgear router. 
The problem is the devices connected with this Netgear WIFI router as you seen above a Laptop on 10.0.0.5 and a Mobile on 10.0.0.10 can't find the Canon printer.
Canon offer an external network card to turn this printer as a network printer to solve such kind of problem. But Can I make this printer available on WIFI network via this process?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr.lock described the best way is to change the Wifi-Router in Bridge mode. In that he has no router function anymore and serve IP-Address from the Mikrotik Router. Not all Wifi-Router support this mode.

If you can't or wan't change this on the Wifi-Router you can solve this with routing as well (are not so nice but works ;)):

Add a new Route on the Mikrotik Router (if the Mikrotik Router the default Gateway):

```
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.30
```

With this new route the Mikrotik Router knows where he can find the Wifi-Network (10.0.0.0/24).

I hope that helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as solution to "close" this thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the WiFi router configuration to run in bridge mode, then the WiFi client will get IP's from the Mikrotick router and be on the same broadcast domain  like the printer

Comment: Thank you Mr. lock for your help. I am able to solve this problem using this method.